# Calling a C function periodically on OSX

Tags: c, macos, function, unix, timer

I have a function which calculates a BPM for a track from incoming data packets from a CDJ. Lets say the BPM was 124.45 beats per minute, how would I go about calling a function every 0.482 seconds (i.e. once per beat)? Would it be possible to set up another thread and set a timer?

Comment: Is the app at all Cocoa? How precise does the timing **need** to be?

Comment: I'm using CoreMidi in the program, if that means anything. If not, then it's all just C. As precise as possible as the function sends a midi tick to a DAW to sync up the clock. I currently have it sending the midi once the packet comes in, which works quite well except the clock is a few ms behind due to latency. I wanted to send the midi a few ms before to try and get the clocks in sync.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a look at high precision timers, [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2169/_index.html) for which Apple claim 500 micrososecond accuracy which is 0.1% of your 500 (ish) millisecond requirement. You can minimise skew by reading the time at the start of your processing and calculating an offset to the next beat. Also, if you find you are often getting scheduled late, and missing beats, you can sleep for, say, 95% of the time to your next beat so the CPU can schedule something else, and then busy wait for the last few percent so you don't hog the CPU.